# drupal 7 form api - countries dropdown

Tags: forms, api, drupal, select

Is there a way to have a full list of countries without building the array manually

```
$options = array(
  '', => 'Please select your country.',
  'USA' => 'USA',
  'UK' => 'UK',
);
```

Is there a way to full in all countries into the array? Petty boring to populate this manually

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal core stores a list of all the countries/codes, handily prepared so you can drop it straight into a form element:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/locale.inc';

$options = country_get_list();
```

Comment: Cool!  I can't believe I didn't know that all this time!

Comment: Is any functions in Drupal 6?